# Pass firebase private key from secret manager to cloud build container

Tags: firebase, docker, go, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-build

I am building a golang application which uses the firebase admin sdk on cloud build  . I created the private key(json file) and stored it in secret manager . I am declaring in my Docker file an `ARG GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and on my build step of the cloudbuild.yaml I am passing the secret as an argument to the docker build.

cloudbuild.yaml :

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--build-arg','GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS','-t', 'us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/something/something:${SHORT_SHA}', '.']
  secretEnv: ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']
availableSecrets: 
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/PROJECT_NAME/versions/1
      env: 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17 as build-env
ARG GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS 
RUN echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

However the echo is not printing the value of the secret which means the secret is not saved as an environment variable . How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: As far as I know, RUN echo will never print out anything in docker build or cloud build

Comment: I have the same issue. When I pass a deterministic value as argument it will be printed as expected, however the secret is printed as $secret_name. Did you figure this out already?

Comment: Not yet @NMeibergen

Answer (score -2):

In the build step where you want to specify the secret, add an **entrypoint** field. The entrypoint field is **required to refer to the environment variable for the secret**.

In the args field, add a -c flag as the first argument. Any string you pass after -c is treated as a command.

In Dockerfiles, an ENTRYPOINT instruction is used to set executables that will always run when the container is initiated. Unlike CMD commands, ENTRYPOINT commands cannot be ignored or overridden—even when the container runs with command line arguments stated.

You may explore more from the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#access-utf8-secrets).

Comment: If my answer was useful you can accept ✔ and upvote  :) Feel free to ask further queries.

Comment: I can't seem to understand how this answer relates to the question.